# XSLT to reach descendant nodes

Tags: xslt

Please suggest to insert the comment text before all 'mfenced' elements which are having 'msub' as thier descendant. However my coding is able to insert the comment text before the first 'mfenced' node, but unable to insert for the other 'mfenced' nodes which are descendant 'mfenced'.

XML:

```
    <root>
  <math display="block">
      <mfenced separators="" open="{" close="">
          <mrow>
              <msub>
                  <mi>t</mi>
                  <mn>2</mn>
              </msub>
              <mfenced separators="" open="{" close="">
                  <mrow>
                      <msub>
                          <mi>t</mi>
                          <mn>3</mn>
                      </msub>
                      <mfenced separators="" open="{" close="">
                          <mrow>
                              <msub>
                                  <mi>t</mi>
                                  <mn>4</mn>
                              </msub>
                          </mrow>
                      </mfenced>
                  </mrow>
              </mfenced>
          </mrow>
      </mfenced>
  </math>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mfenced">
      <xsl:if test="descendant::msub">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--false buildup--&gt;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required OutPut:

For this input XML, there should be three 'false buildup' comment text. Please suggest. (I am using XSLT2 version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should do although I would move the condition into the match pattern, would create the comment using `xsl:comment` and would simply use `next-match`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mfenced[descendant::msub]">
      <xsl:comment select="'false buildup'"/>
      <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using Saxon 9.5 that transforms the input

```
<root>
  <math display="block">
      <mfenced separators="" open="{" close="">
          <mrow>
              <msub>
                  <mi>t</mi>
                  <mn>2</mn>
              </msub>
              <mfenced separators="" open="{" close="">
                  <mrow>
                      <msub>
                          <mi>t</mi>
                          <mn>3</mn>
                      </msub>
                      <mfenced separators="" open="{" close="">
                          <mrow>
                              <msub>
                                  <mi>t</mi>
                                  <mn>4</mn>
                              </msub>
                          </mrow>
                      </mfenced>
                  </mrow>
              </mfenced>
          </mrow>
      </mfenced>
  </math>
</root>
```

into the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <math display="block">
      <!--false buildup--><mfenced separators="" open="{" close="">
          <mrow>
              <msub>
                  <mi>t</mi>
                  <mn>2</mn>
              </msub>
              <!--false buildup--><mfenced separators="" open="{" close="">
                  <mrow>
                      <msub>
                          <mi>t</mi>
                          <mn>3</mn>
                      </msub>
                      <!--false buildup--><mfenced separators="" open="{" close="">
                          <mrow>
                              <msub>
                                  <mi>t</mi>
                                  <mn>4</mn>
                              </msub>
                          </mrow>
                      </mfenced>
                  </mrow>
              </mfenced>
          </mrow>
      </mfenced>
  </math>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your suggestion. I got the required result. Once again thanks for more answers from you for earlier questions too.